# Expected Number of Rolls Until the sequence 6,6,5?

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, expected-value, generating-functions, conditional-expectation

I've seen the recursive expected value approach to solving this problem but I am interested in how to solve this from a generating function perspective.

Let E be the expected number of rolls, and X the value of a given roll.

My current setup for the generating function is as follows. Each is a distinct sequence that could precede 6,6,5.

$\lnot (X = 6)  = \frac 56x $ 
$(X = 6) \land \lnot(X = 6)  = \frac {5}{36}x^2$

The problem I run into is this step. Assuming we get 6,6, there are 3 outcomes. We can get 5 and be done, we can get 1 through 4 and have to go again, or we can get 6, in which case we need another 5 to be done. I am not sure how to model this with the generating function. My current approach is this:

$(X = 6) \land (X = 6) \land \lnot(X = 6 \lor X= 5) = \frac {4}{216}x^3$

$(X = 6) \land (X = 6) \land (X= 5) = \frac {1}{216}x^3$

$(X = 6) \land (X = 6) \land (X= 6) = \frac {1}{216}x^3$

$(X= 5) = \frac {1}{6}x$

We thus have 2 different setups; either we got a 6, 6, and a non-6 or non-5 and have to start over till we get a 6,6,5, or we got 6 and have to roll until we get a 5:

$$\sum_{i = 0}^\infty (\frac 56x + \frac {5}{36}x^2 + \frac {4}{216}x^3)^i(\frac {1}{216}x^3) + \sum_{i = 0}^\infty(\frac{1}{216}x^3)^i(\frac 16x)$$

Is this correct? If not, how should I setup the generating function?

Additionally, generally speaking, how do I get the expected value from the generating function? That is, what are the next steps?

Comment: This is difficult to follow. It would help to use $X_k, X_{k+1}$, etc. rather than apparently one symbol $X$ for many different things. And for each generating function involved, it would help to state in words exactly what the coefficients represent.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do a first step analysis using a Markovian approach ?

Let $a$ be the starting state, $b$ the state where we have just rolled a $6,$ and $c$ the state where we have just rolled two consecutive $6's$,then

With one toss from start, we either roll a $6$ with $Pr = \frac16$, or remain put with $Pr =\frac56$

Framing equations step by step, we get
$\displaylines{a = 1+b/6 +5a/6 \\b = 1+c/6 +5a/6,\\c = 1 + c/6 +4a/6  }$
[The last equation means that with one step either you are done, stay put, or revert]

Solve to get $a = 216$

Comment: Thanks - the stateful modeling definitely simplifies both the calculation and conceptual aspects of this problem. That being said, if this were to use a generating function solution, is my approach accurate?

Comment: I don't know too much about g.f's, I'll refer it to a g.f. specialist.

Comment: @Bulbasaur: My friend, here's something right in your line !